# How to run application from command prompt with arguments?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-7, environment-variables

I have an application named DriveMaster which I want to run from command line with different arguments. The application is residing in:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe\"
```

Now in Windows - Run, if I open command prompt and want to give a command like:

```
 DriveMaster /s:Scriptname.srt
```

This should be able to launch DriveMaster with that particular script.

How can I do this? What should I need to add in the Environment variables so that I can run the application from command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7:

- In the menu Start click Computer
- In the context menu, select System Properties
- Select Advanced System Settings -> tab Advanced
- Select Environment Variables Menu System Variables to find the PATH variable and click it.
- In the editing window, change the PATH, adding value: ; C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970
- Open Run and type: DriveMaster /s:Scriptname.srt

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In a file name `drivemaster.bat` whch would be located at some point in the path,

```
@echo off
setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe" /s:Scriptname.srt
```

where `Scriptname.srt` would need to be quoted and supplied with a full pathname if it's not in the current directory.

---

Oh you want to type `DriveMaster /s:Scriptname.srt`

Then use

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe" %1
```

in that script in place of the original "c:..." line.

edit : removed stray terminal backslash from ...exe

Comment: I created a batch file: @echo off
setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe\" %1     Getting an error: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster.exe\"' is not rec
ognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the command prompt the **working directory** is given in the prompt:

```
C:\Users>
```

Here, I'm in the folder `C:\Users`. If I want to run a program or a script in the folder I'm currently in, I can use its name alone (e.g. `DriveMaster`). If the program is outside my working directory, I can't call it like that because there could be many `DriveMasters` in different folders throughout my computer. I can either change my directory to be the one that has this program, or I can specify where in the filesystem it's located.

Changing the directory and running:

```
C:\Users> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\"
C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970> DriveMaster
```

Specifying the full path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970\DriveMaster"
```

(I need to use quotes here because the folder names have spaces and my command prompt may not know if it's part of the folder name or the beginning of another command or argument.)

On the same line I call the program, I can choose a number of **arguments** (also called options, switches, flags) to change the way to program behaves. If my program accepts another file and wants it in the form `/s:` and-then-the-filename, that file also needs to be in my working directory. If it lives somewhere else, I can use the full specification, like I've done above.

**Environment variables** are a little more complicated of a topic, but there is one we might be interested in here. The `Path` environment variable is a list of folders that the command prompt will look in when you try to use names of files that aren't in your working directory. If I know I'm going to be using this program frequently and like where it is, I can add its folder to my `Path` so that I can access it with just `DriveMaster` in the future:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\ULINK DM2012 PRO NET\v970
```

(If I mistype that command, though, I could break other things in a way that would be hard to fix.)